# Iterating to figure out combinations of variable number of elements

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm making a program that uses dynamic programming to decide how to distribute some files (Movies) among DVDs so that it uses the least number of DVDs.

After much thought I decided that a good way to do it is to look at every possible combination of movies that is less than 4.38 GB (The actual size of a DVD ) and pick the largest one (i.e. the one that wastes the least space) and remove the movies in the most efficient combination and repeat until it run out of movies.

The problem is that I don't know how to loop so I can figure out every possible combination, given that movies vary in size, so a specific number of nested loops cannot be used.

pseudo-code:

```
Some kind of loop:
    best_combination=[]
    best_combination_size=0
    if current_combination<4.38 and current_combination>best_combination_size:
        best_combination=current_combination
        best_combination_size=best_combination_size
print(best_combination)
delete best_combination from list_of_movies
```

first time to post a question..so go easy on me guys!!
Thanks in advance

P.S. I figured out a way to do it using Dijkstra's which I think would be fast but not memory friendly. If anybody is interested i would gladly discuss it.

Comment: What you propose is a heuristic and not a global optimal solution. If you are okay with this, it would be much easier to stick to common **bin-packing** heuristics. The wikipedia-article on bin-packing should also guide you to optimal dynamic-programming approaches (which i would not use; i would start with the heuristic-approach).

Comment: Another remark: as Dijkstra's algorithm is in P, the problem in NP, it's very unlikely that your idea will work (optimal solution; even the pick from all movies; fill one DVD as close as possible problem)

Comment: Thank you sascha. So what do you suggest as a 'global optimal solution' ?

Comment: DP-based approaches (on the full problem, not filling DVD **after** DVD) might work. Mixed-integer programming based approaches would be possibly better (when tuned). But as it's a NP-complete problem, there will always be tough instances (in theory).

Comment: Approximately how many movies in total? Also, what's an example difference between an optimally-packed DVD and a DVD that's not optimally packed (like how many movies)? Also, what's the distribution of movie lengths (like how many are about 90 min, how many are 120 min, etc.) and how many minutes fit on one DVD? Also, is length the only characteristic considered when packing movies in one DVD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really stick to [common bin-packing heuristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). The wikipedia article gives a good overview of approaches including links to problem-tailored exact approaches. But always keep in mind: **it's an np-complete problem!**

I will show you some example supporting my hint, that you should stick to heuristics.

The following python-code:

- creates **parameterized random-problems** (normal-distribution on multiple means/stds; acceptance-sampling to make sure that no movie is bigger than a DVD)
- **uses some random binpacking-library which implements some greedy-heuristic** (i didn't try or test this lib before; so no guarantees!; no idea which heuristic is used)
- uses a **naive mixed-integer programming implementation** (which is solved by a **commercial solver**; open-source solvers like cbc struggle, but might be used for good approximate solutions)

#### Code

```python
import numpy as np
from cvxpy import *
from time import time

""" Generate some test-data """
np.random.seed(1)
N = 150  # movies
means = [700, 1400, 4300]
stds = [100, 300, 500]
DVD_SIZE = 4400

movies = []
for movie in range(N):
    while True:
        random_mean_index = np.random.randint(low=0, high=len(means))
        random_size = np.random.randn() * stds[random_mean_index] + means[random_mean_index]
        if random_size <= DVD_SIZE:
            movies.append(random_size)
            break

""" HEURISTIC SOLUTION """
import binpacking
start = time()
bins = binpacking.to_constant_volume(movies, DVD_SIZE)
end = time()
print('Heuristic solution: ')
for b in bins:
    print(b)
print('used bins: ', len(bins))
print('used time (seconds): ', end-start)

""" Preprocessing """
movie_sizes_sorted = sorted(movies)
max_movies_per_dvd = 0
occupied = 0
for i in range(N):
    if occupied + movie_sizes_sorted[i] <= DVD_SIZE:
        max_movies_per_dvd += 1
        occupied += movie_sizes_sorted[i]
    else:
        break

""" Solve problem """
# Variables
X = Bool(N, N)  # N * number-DVDS
I = Bool(N)     # indicator: DVD used

# Constraints
constraints = []
# (1) DVDs not overfilled
for dvd in range(N):
    constraints.append(sum_entries(mul_elemwise(movies, X[:, dvd])) <= DVD_SIZE)
# (2) All movies distributed exactly once
for movie in range(N):
    constraints.append(sum_entries(X[movie, :]) == 1)
# (3) Indicators
for dvd in range(N):
    constraints.append(sum_entries(X[:, dvd]) <= I[dvd] * (max_movies_per_dvd + 1))

# Objective
objective = Minimize(sum_entries(I))

# Problem
problem = Problem(objective, constraints)
start = time()
problem.solve(solver=GUROBI, MIPFocus=1, verbose=True)
#problem.solve(solver=CBC, CliqueCuts=True)#, GomoryCuts=True, KnapsackCuts=True, verbose=True)#, GomoryCuts=True, MIRCuts=True, ProbingCuts=True,
              #CliqueCuts=True, FlowCoverCuts=True, LiftProjectCuts=True,
              #verbose=True)
end = time()

""" Print solution """
for dvd in range(N):
    movies_ = []
    for movie in range(N):
        if np.isclose(X.value[movie, dvd], 1):
            movies_.append(movies[movie])
    if movies_:
        print('DVD')
        for movie in movies_:
            print('     movie with size: ', movie)

print('Distributed ', N, ' movies to ', int(objective.value), ' dvds')
print('Optimizatio took (seconds): ', end-start)
```

#### Partial Output

```
Heuristic solution:
-------------------
('used bins: ', 60)
('used time (seconds): ', 0.0045168399810791016)

MIP-approach:
-------------
Root relaxation: objective 2.142857e+01, 1921 iterations, 0.10 seconds

    Nodes    |    Current Node    |     Objective Bounds      |     Work
 Expl Unexpl |  Obj  Depth IntInf | Incumbent    BestBd   Gap | It/Node Time

     0     0   21.42857    0  120  106.00000   21.42857  79.8%     -    0s
H    0     0                      68.0000000   21.42857  68.5%     -    0s
H    0     0                      63.0000000   21.42857  66.0%     -    0s
     0     0   21.42857    0  250   63.00000   21.42857  66.0%     -    1s
H    0     0                      62.0000000   21.42857  65.4%     -    2s
     0     0   21.42857    0  256   62.00000   21.42857  65.4%     -    2s
     0     0   21.42857    0  304   62.00000   21.42857  65.4%     -    2s
     0     0   21.42857    0  109   62.00000   21.42857  65.4%     -    3s
     0     2   21.42857    0  108   62.00000   21.42857  65.4%     -    4s
    40     2   27.61568   20   93   62.00000   27.61568  55.5%   110    5s
H  156    10                      61.0000000   58.00000  4.92%  55.3    8s
   262     4   59.00000   84   61   61.00000   59.00000  3.28%  44.2   10s
   413    81 infeasible  110        61.00000   59.00000  3.28%  37.2   15s
H  417    78                      60.0000000   59.00000  1.67%  36.9   15s
  1834  1212   59.00000  232   40   60.00000   59.00000  1.67%  25.7   20s
...
...
 57011 44660 infeasible  520        60.00000   59.00000  1.67%  27.1  456s
 57337 44972   59.00000  527   34   60.00000   59.00000  1.67%  27.1  460s
 58445 45817   59.00000   80   94   60.00000   59.00000  1.67%  26.9  466s
 59387 46592   59.00000  340   65   60.00000   59.00000  1.67%  26.8  472s
```

#### Analysis

Some observations regarding the example above:

- the heuristic obtains some solution of value 60 instantly
- the commercial-solver needs more time but also find a solution of value 60 (15 secs)

  - also tries to find a better solution or proof that there is no one (MIP-solvers are complete = find optimal solution or proof there is none given infinite time!)
  - no progress for some time!
  - but: **we got proof, that there is at best a solution of size 59**
  - = **maybe** you will save one DVD by solving the problem optimally; but it's hard to find a solution and we don't know if this solution exists (yet)!

#### Remarks

- The observations above are heavily dependent on data-statistics
- It's easy to try other problems (maybe smaller) where the commercial MIP-solver finds a solution which uses 1 less DVD (e.g. 49 vs. 50)

  - It's not worth it (remember: open-source solvers are struggling even more)
  - The formulation is very simple and not tuned at all (don't blame only the solvers)
- There are exact algorithms (which might be much more complex to implement) which could be appropriate

#### Conclusion

**Heuristics are very easy to implement and provide very good solutions in general. Most of these also come with very good theoretical guarantees (e.g. at most 11/9 opt + 1 #DVDs compared to optimal solution are used = first fit decreasing heuristic)**. Despite the fact, that i'm keen on optimization in general, i probably would use the heuristics-approach here.

The general problem is also very popular, so that there should exist some good library for this problem in many programming-languages!

Comment: Thank you for this answer. You did an amazing job explaining it. And a better job formatting and structuring the answer. 
I want to know where did you learn about heuristics and NP problems?

Comment: @MazenSharkawy Well, i'm a student of computer science and learned the basic algorithms stuff and a bit more advanced courses on parts of complexity-theory at the university (expander graphs still give me nightmares). The last years i'm more interested in mathematical-optimization (which nicely blends with machine-learning sometimes), which i partly learned at university, but the more advanced stuff i learned from available university-courses (especially Stephen Boyds group @ stanford). And thanks for your nice words!

Answer (score 0):

Without claiming, that the solution this answer presents is optimized, optimal or possesses any other remarkable qualities, here a greedy approach to the dvd packing problem.

```hs
import System.Random
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

-- F# programmers are so used to this operator, I just cannot live without it ...yet.
(|>) a b = b a 
data Dvd = Dvd { duration :: Int, movies :: [Int] } deriving (Show,Eq)

dvdCapacity = 1000 :: Int -- a dvd has capacity for 1000 time units - arbitrary unit
-- the duration of a movie is between 1 and 1000 time units
r = randomRs (1,1000) (mkStdGen 42) :: [Int] 
-- our test data set of 1000 movies, random movie durations drawn from r
allMovies = zip [1..1000] (take 1000 r)     
allMoviesSorted = reverse $ sortBy (comparing snd) allMovies
remainingCapacity dvd = dvdCapacity - duration dvd

emptyDvd = Dvd { duration = 0, movies = [] }

-- from the remaining movies, pick the largest one with at most maxDuration length.
pickLargest remaining maxDuration =
    let (left,right) = remaining |> break (\ (a,b) -> b <= maxDuration)
        (h,t) = case right of 
            [] -> (Nothing,[]) 
            otherwise -> (Just (head right), right |> tail)
        in 
            (h,[left, t] |> concat)

-- add a track (movie) to a dvd
addTrack dvd track = 
    Dvd {duration = (duration dvd) + snd track, 
        movies = fst track : (movies dvd) }

-- pick dvd from dvds with largest remaining capacity 
-- and add the largest remaining fitting track
greedyPack movies dvds 
    | movies == [] = (dvds,[])
    | otherwise =

        let dvds' = reverse $ sortBy (comparing remainingCapacity) dvds
            (picked,movies') =
                case dvds' of
                    [] -> (Nothing, movies)
                    (x:xs) -> pickLargest movies (remainingCapacity x)
            in
                case picked of
                    Nothing ->
                        -- None of the current dvds had enough capacity remaining
                        -- tp pick another movie and add it. -> Add new empty dvd
                        -- and run greedyPack again. 
                        greedyPack movies' (emptyDvd : dvds')
                    Just p ->
                        -- The best fitting movie could be added to the 
                        -- dvd with the largest remaining capacity.
                        greedyPack movies' (addTrack (head dvds') p : tail dvds')   

(result,residual) = greedyPack allMoviesSorted [emptyDvd] 
usedDvdsCount = length result
totalPlayTime = allMovies |> foldl (\ s (i,d) -> s + d) 0
optimalDvdsCount = round $ 0.5 + fromIntegral totalPlayTime / fromIntegral dvdCapacity
solutionQuality = length result - optimalDvdsCount
```

Compared to the theoretical optimal dvd count it wastes 4 extra dvds on the given data set.